# How to preserve datatype following a SELECT INTO?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table `T1` with some Date/Time fields.  I've combined several queries on this table with a UNION query, and made a new table `T2` using SELECT INTO on the union as follows:

```
SELECT * INTO T2
FROM (select * from query1_T1
union
select * from query2_T1)
```

The problem is that `query1_T1` substitutes a blank string constant for some of the date fields, which results in T2 having Text fields instead of Date/Time fields.  To illustrate:

```
query1_T1:
select myUDF(someTextField),"" as newDateField from T1

query2_T1:
select anotherUDF(someTextField),oldDateField from T1
```

where `oldDateField` is a Date/Time.

Is there a way that I can structure the SELECT INTO, or change `query1_T1`, so that I'll still get the same results from the query but `newDateField` will end up as a Date/Time?

Comment: Do you have to use `SELECT INTO` to create the table? Or can you create the structure separately and then insert the data later?

Comment: @imthepitts, that worked quite well.  I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always create the table separately from adding the data into it. First, define all the fields with the appropriate data types. Then use `INSERT INTO (columns) SELECT * FROM` to populate it.

**UPDATED:**

Or you can do a hybrid approach. First do your `SELECT INTO` with **no rows at all**:

```
SELECT * INTO T2
FROM query2_T1
WHERE 1=0
```

This will create most of your structure. Then you can go and manually adjust any data types that didn't come through properly.

With the structure properly adjusted, you can do this safely:

```
INSERT INTO T2 
SELECT * FROM query1_T1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM query2_T1
```

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson! I actually employed this same process recently on my current project. So it was fresh in my mind. :o)

Comment: I realise this is an old one, but, if the table has occurrences of every field being used at some point, then you can automate the process a little further by grouping and  selecting the `MIN` value for every field, e.g.: `SELECT MIN([people].[forename]), MIN([people].[surname]), MIN([people].[dob]) FROM query1_T1 WHERE 1=0` to force the type.

Answer (score 2):

You can work around the issue by simply

- changing `query1_T1` to return `Null` instead of an empty string as the second column, and
- reversing the order of the queries that you UNION together

That is,

```
SELECT * INTO T2
FROM 
(
select * from query2_T1
UNION ALL
select * from query1_T1
)
```

That way, the second column contains *some* date values when the table structure of T2 is determined by the first of the UNIONed queries, and the second query does not force the column to Text afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this in Access, but you can use `cast()` in almost any other database.  The equivalent function in Access is `cdate()`.  Try:

```
cdate(NULL) as newDateField
```

If you need an actual value, then something like:

```
cdate('1900-01-01')
```